# How to store and retrieve images in sqlite database in android?

Tags: android

I am working on **quiz application** and I need to display **questions along with images**. I have **stored the questions in sqlite database** and **displaying them in android**. But I dont know how to  store the images in sqlite db and display them. 
    I have gone through so many links and found how to display an image from remote db. But I **need to display images from local sqlite db**. How can I do that. Please help me regarding this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 2):

You generally don't save binary data to a database. It's considered bad form and can make queries to the database take really long because of the way the data ends up getting stored on the disk. What you should do is store a file path to the image in your database and store the image on the sdcard.

Without writing massive amounts of code for you, here's a high-level example. First, create your table to store the image with the following sql call:

```
CREATE TABLE images (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOICREMENT, file_path TEXT, name TEXT);
```

When it comes time to insert an image you have to do two things. First, write the image out to the SD card. Follow the instructions here to do that. Once you've written it out and gotten a file name for it, you just do a sql query like so:

```
INSERT INTO images (file_path, name) VALUES ("your file path", "name of image");
```

Whenever you actually need to display the image, you just read the file specified by file_path from your sdcard.

Comment: I would add that if you don't have many images and/or they're small, look at storing them locally instead of the sdcard. If you have a lot of stuff, or it updates dynamically, don't do this. If the space you're taking up is relatively small, though, storing them locally means you don't have to worry so much about what happens if the sdcard data is suddenly gone, or the sdcard is not available (both possible).

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of actually answering your stated question, if you REALLY want to write the image to the DB you would add a BLOB field and store the data in that, but there's no reason to do this... just follow Kurtis Nusbaum's advice and store the image as a file with a reference in the db row as to where it is.