# Retrieving sqlite blob field to put into imageview

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having problems trying to retrieve a blob from my sqlite database and setting it as a bitmap in the imageview that is a layout that my listview uses. The text from the database is fine but I get an error when I try to set the imageview to the bitmap that has been read in from the database. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.*;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;


public class StudentTrackerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    final static int cameraData = 0;
    private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 192837; 
    private static final String BUFF_INFO = null;
    public byte[] imgByte = null;
    public final Bitmap imgBitmap = null;
    public ImageView imgPic; 
    public ImageButton imgCamera;
    public ImageView imgSpeaker;
    public ImageView imgIcon;

    public Bitmap bm;
    public Intent i;
    public ByteArrayOutputStream out =  new ByteArrayOutputStream(128);
    InputStream is;
    StringBuffer sb; 
    Button btnAddStudentRecord;

    boolean bRecordAdded = true;

    public ListView list;
    public EditText txtStudentName;
    public EditText txtDOB;
    public EditText txtAddress1;
    public EditText txtAddress2;
    public EditText txtTown;
    public EditText txtPostcode;
    public EditText txtPhone;

    public TextView txtFname;
    public TextView txtDateOfBirth; 

    public String strStudentName;
    public String strDOB;
    public String strAddress1;
    public String strAddress2;
    public String strTown; 
    public String strPostcode;
    public String strPhone;

    public String strMatches;
    public List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        sb = new StringBuffer();
        imgCamera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgCamera);
        imgPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPic);
        imgSpeaker = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSpeaker);
        imgIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        btnAddStudentRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddStudentRecord);

        txtStudentName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtStudentName);
        txtDOB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDOB);
        txtAddress1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddress1);
        txtAddress2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddress2);
        txtTown = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTown);       
        txtPostcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPostcode);
        txtPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);

        txtFname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFname);
       // txtDateOfBirth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDateOfBirth);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        //convert edit text values to string values
        strStudentName = txtStudentName.getText().toString();
        strDOB = txtDOB.getText().toString(); 
        strAddress1 = txtAddress1.getText().toString();
        strAddress2 = txtAddress2.getText().toString(); 
        strTown= txtTown.getText().toString(); 
        strPostcode = txtPostcode.getText().toString();
        strPhone = txtPhone.getText().toString();




        TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        th.setup();
        TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        specs.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.student));
        th.addTab(specs);

        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        specs.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.camera));
        th.addTab(specs);

        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        specs.setIndicator("Tab3");
        th.addTab(specs);

        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag4");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab4);
        specs.setIndicator("Search", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.magnify));
        th.addTab(specs);

       //set listener for speaker button 
        imgSpeaker.setOnClickListener(new SpeakerButtonHandler());

       //set listener for camera button 
       imgCamera.setOnClickListener(this);

       //set listener for add student button 
       btnAddStudentRecord.setOnClickListener(new AddStuButtonHandler());

       //make silhouette default image
       is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.silhouette);
       bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

       //display students in listview
       DisplayaAllStudents();




    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

      int vNum = v.getId();

      switch(vNum){

      case R.id.imgCamera:

          //capture photo of student
          i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);

          break;


      }

    }

       private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            //intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
            startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

       public void flushBuffer(){

           sb.delete(0, sb.length());

       }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        try{


            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                 Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                 bm = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
                 imgPic.setImageBitmap(bm);


            }

              if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
                    ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                    //add text to string buffer and display 
                    //it on notepad

                    //flush string buffer of previous content
                    flushBuffer();

                    //remove square brackets
                    strMatches = matches.toString().replace("[","").replace("]", "");

                    //add string to string buffer
                    sb.append(strMatches.toString() + "\n");

                    //check which edit text field has the 
                    //focus then populate the field with the
                    //contents of the voice recognition string

                    if(txtStudentName.isFocused()){

                    txtStudentName.setText(sb.toString());

                    }
                    else if(txtDOB.isFocused()){

                    txtDOB.setText(sb.toString());

                    }
                    else if(txtAddress1.isFocused()){

                        txtAddress1.setText(sb.toString());

                    }

                    else if(txtAddress2.isFocused()){

                        txtAddress2.setText(sb.toString());

                    } 

                    else if(txtTown.isFocused()){

                        txtTown.setText(sb.toString());

                     }

                    else if(txtPostcode.isFocused()){

                        txtPostcode.setText(sb.toString());
                     }  

                    else if(txtPhone.isFocused()){

                        txtPhone.setText(sb.toString());
                     }

            }

        }catch(Exception ex){


            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class AddStuButtonHandler implements OnClickListener{


        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(v.getId() == R.id.btnAddStudentRecord){

                addRecord();

                //DisplayaAllStudents();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Testing!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }





    }

    public void addRecord(){

        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

        db.open();
        long id;
        //prepare and compress bitmap for database insert       
        bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

        id = db.insertStudent(txtStudentName.getText().toString(),
                txtDOB.getText().toString(),
                txtAddress1.getText().toString(),
                txtAddress2.getText().toString(),
                txtTown.getText().toString(),
                txtPostcode.getText().toString(),
                txtPhone.getText().toString(),
                out.toByteArray()

                );

        if(bRecordAdded){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: could not add record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        db.close();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void DisplayaAllStudents(){

         DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

         db.open();

         Cursor c = db.getAllStudents();

         if(c.moveToFirst()){

             do{

                 String stuName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_STUDENTNAME));
                 String stuDOB = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_DOB));

                 results.add(" " + stuName.toString() + ", D.O.B: " + stuDOB);
                 //read image from database and insert into image view
                 imgByte = c.getBlob(8);
                 ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imgByte);

                 Bitmap picBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                 imgIcon.setImageBitmap(picBitmap);


                 //display record
                 //DisplayStudent(c);
             }while(c.moveToNext());
         }
        //bind data to list view
         list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(StudentTrackerActivity.this,R.layout.datalayout,R.id.txtFname,results));

         db.close();
    }

    public void DisplayStudent(Cursor c){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

                "StudentName: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                "D.O.B:" + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                "Address1: " + c.getString(3) + "\n" +
                "Address2: " + c.getString(4) + "\n" +
                "Town: " + c.getString(5) + "\n" +
                "Postcode: " + c.getString(6) + "\n" +
                "Phone: " + c.getString(7) + "\n" +
                "Pic: " + c.getBlob(8)
                ,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }



   private class SpeakerButtonHandler implements OnClickListener{


    public void onClick(View v) {


        if(v.getId() == R.id.imgSpeaker){

            startVoiceRecognitionActivity();


        }

     }



  }

}
```

---

```
11-17 13:22:58.506: INFO/System.out(25430): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-17 13:22:58.707: INFO/System.out(25430): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-17 13:22:58.907: INFO/System.out(25430): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-17 13:22:59.109: INFO/System.out(25430): debugger has settled (1463)
11-17 13:22:59.307: ERROR/gralloc(126): [unregister] handle 0x393b98 still locked (state=40000001)
11-17 13:23:00.127: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): updateAllElements
11-17 13:23:00.127: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): updateTime
11-17 13:23:00.127: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): setCalendarInstance
11-17 13:23:00.127: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): onTimeChanged
11-17 13:23:00.127: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): mHour01HandIndex = 1
11-17 13:23:00.127: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): mHour01HandIndex = 3
11-17 13:23:00.127: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): mHour01HandIndex = 2
11-17 13:23:00.127: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): mHour01HandIndex = 3
11-17 13:23:00.127: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): updateTime id = 3
11-17 13:23:00.127: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): updateCurrentTemperature
11-17 13:23:00.127: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): changeFtoC
11-17 13:23:00.137: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): updateCurrentLocal
11-17 13:23:00.147: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): updateTemperatures
11-17 13:23:00.147: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): setCalendarInstance
11-17 13:23:00.177: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): highT = 60
11-17 13:23:00.177: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): lowT = 47
11-17 13:23:00.177: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): changeFtoC
11-17 13:23:00.197: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): changeFtoC
11-17 13:23:00.197: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): updateDate
11-17 13:23:00.197: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): setCalendarInstance
11-17 13:23:00.207: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): updateWeatherDescription
11-17 13:23:00.207: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): updateUpdatedTime
11-17 13:23:00.207: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): setCalendarInstance
11-17 13:23:00.207: ERROR/updateUpdatedTime dateString(5101): 11/13/2011
11-17 13:23:00.237: ERROR/updatedTime before(5101):  Update: NOV.13 4:14 PM
11-17 13:23:00.237: ERROR/updatedTime end(5101):  Update: NOV.13 4:14 PM
11-17 13:23:00.297: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): bindViews
11-17 13:23:00.297: INFO/WeatherClockWidgetProvider(5101): appWidgetId = 3
11-17 13:23:03.157: WARN/wpa_supplicant(189): Failed to initiate AP scan.
11-17 13:23:05.517: WARN/ActivityManager(126): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
11-17 13:23:05.777: WARN/ActivityManager(126): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{447ec880 com.StudentTracker/.StudentTrackerActivity}
11-17 13:23:07.467: WARN/GDataClient(126): Unable to execute HTTP request.java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: android.clients.google.com:443
11-17 13:23:09.161: WARN/wpa_supplicant(189): Failed to initiate AP scan.
11-17 13:23:15.162: WARN/wpa_supplicant(189): Failed to initiate AP scan.
```

---

Stack trace:

```
StudentTracker_Debug [Android Application]  
    DalvikVM[localhost:8603]    
        Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
            ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2496  
            ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2512   
            ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 119 
            ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1863  
            ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
            Looper.loop() line: 123 
            ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4363    
            Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
            Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
            ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 860  
            ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 618 
            NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, do you have a stack trace you can post? This is just your LogCat of system events.

Comment: I've included the stack trace

Answer (score 3):

Don't put images in your database. It's just bad form in general and is going to make your database queries really slow. Instead, store the filepath to your image in the database and load the image as needed. Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112702/how-to-store-and-retrieve-images-in-sqlite-database-in-android/8112711#8112711) for a more detailed answer.